# Left join equivalent

Tags: stata

I have in Stata Data1.dta as:

```
ID  Hospital
1   Hospital A
2   Hospital B
3   Hospital C
```

I have Data2.dta as:

```
ID  Discharge
1   Y
1   N
3   Y
```

I want to left join Data1 to Data2. The resulting dataset should look like:

```
ID  Hospital    Discharge
1   Hospital A  Y
1   Hospital A  N
2   Hospital B  .
3   Hospital C  Y
```

I have tried

```
merge m:m ID using "filepath/Data2.dta"
```

It runs without errors but I'm having a hard time interpreting the results especially the 'not matched' and 'matched' categories are confusing because I want everything in Data1.dta and only matching values from Data2.dta (ie. kind of both) and also because I'm new to Stata.

Comment: Check out -joinby-.

Comment: I used the joinby as: joinby ID using "filepath/Data2.dta". It ran without errors but the resulting data is like a inner join rather than a left join(i.e. I want to retain all obs from Data1 regardless of their match with Data2). Do I need to modify the joinby statement that retains all observations on the left?

Comment: Read this https://www.stata.com/manuals/djoinby.pdf and modified the statement to: joinby ID using "filepath/Data2.dta", unmatched(master). It seems to work. Thanks Nick!